# Private Ethereum : Got error (Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds) when saving migration to chain on a private Ethereum network

Tags: ethereum, truffle, geth

I tried to migrate the contract Migrations by using Truffle migrate, it got hang and show error message as belows. Please help me if I configured anything wrong.

⠸ Saving migration to chain.   {
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "id": 1574154369501,
      "result": "0x"
    }

Error: Error: Error: Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:92:1)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
Truffle v5.1.0 (core: 5.1.0)
Node v8.10.0

Answer (score 1):

This problem was fixed. The root cause was an environment. At the first time I ran this on VirtualBox Ubantu. The performance was quite slow. Then I tried to run on Host Windows. It's fast and worked.

Comment: when was this problem fixed? I have the same issue, and I am using the last version, Truffle v5.1.31 (core: 5.1.31). Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js). Node v12.18.1. Web3.js v1.2.1

Comment: The version that you use should be fine. My issue is about the network speed.

Comment: if i remember correctly, i solved the problem by setting a correct gas price; before it was way too low.